# Finding unique hash value within array of hashes (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
a[0] = {:id => '1234', :value => '37'}
a[1] = {:id => '4321', :value => '50'}
a[2] = {:id => '1122', :value => '50'}
```

From here I want to be able to check to see if a hash exists with :id => '4321' without having to loop through the array manually.  Is there anything where I can do something like this: a.exists?(:id => '4321') ?  I've tried a few things but can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
a.any? {|x| x[:id] == '4321' }
```

That will return `true` if the block returns `true`.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794039/how-to-find-a-hash-key-containing-a-matching-value - but a different operation that I needed, thanks!