# How to find a hash key containing a matching value

Tags: ruby

Given I have the below **clients** hash, is there a quick ruby way (without having to write a multi-line script) to obtain the key given I want to match the client_id? E.g. How to get the key for `client_id == "2180"`?

```
clients = {
  "yellow"=>{"client_id"=>"2178"}, 
  "orange"=>{"client_id"=>"2180"}, 
  "red"=>{"client_id"=>"2179"}, 
  "blue"=>{"client_id"=>"2181"}
}
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable#select](http://rubydoc.info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/Enumerable:select):

```
clients.select{|key, hash| hash["client_id"] == "2180" }
#=> [["orange", {"client_id"=>"2180"}]]
```

Note that the result will be an array of all the matching values, where each is an array of the key and value.

Comment: @Coderama The difference between `find` and `select` is that `find` returns the first match and `select` (which is aliased by `findAll`) returns all matches.

Comment: I see, so this would be the safer option for instances where there is more than one match.

Comment: This is better than creating a whole new hash (by calling `invert`) just to find an item.

Comment: Note that as of [Ruby 1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select), this will return a new hash with the matches. It will not return an array, as it [used to in Ruby <= 1.8.7](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select).

`clients.select{|key, hash| hash["client_id"] == "2180" }
# => {"orange"=>{"client_id"=>"2180"}}`

Comment: To get the key(s), simply put `clients.select{|key, hash| hash["client_id"] == "2180" }.keys`

Answer (score 480):

**Ruby 1.9** and greater:

```
hash.key(value) => key
```

**Ruby 1.8**:

You could use [`hash.index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002855)

> `hsh.index(value) => key`
>
> Returns the key for a given value. If
>   not found, returns `nil`.
>
> `h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }`
>   `h.index(200)   #=> "b"`
>   `h.index(999)   #=> nil`

So to get `"orange"`, you could just use:

```
clients.key({"client_id" => "2180"})
```

Comment: This would get kind of messy if the hashes had multiple keys, because you'd need to give the entire hash to `index`.

Comment: `Hash#index` is renamed to `Hash#key` in Ruby 1.9

Comment: Note that this only returns the first match, if there are multiple hash pairings with the same value, it'll return the first key with a matching value.

Answer (score 50):

You can invert the hash. `clients.invert["client_id"=>"2180"]` returns `"orange"`

Comment: This also seems like a clever way (because it's short) to do it!

Comment: this is what i need for form arrays (for select boxes) which create a backwards hash

Answer (score 24):

You could use hashname.key(valuename)

Or, an inversion may be in order. `new_hash = hashname.invert` will give you a `new_hash` that lets you do things more traditionally.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it in recent versions (1.9+) of Ruby.

Comment: `#invert` is a really bad idea in this case, since you are essentially allocating memory for throw-away hash object just for the sake of finding a key. Depending on hash size it have serious performance impact

Answer (score 20):

try this:

```
clients.find{|key,value| value["client_id"] == "2178"}.first
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the find returns nil, because you can't call .first on nil.

Comment: If using Rails you can use `.try(:first)` instead of `.first` to avoid exceptions (If you are expecting it to be possible for the value to be missing).

Comment: in `Ruby 2.3.0 +` you can use [safe navigator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)  `&.first` at the end of block to prevent from Nil Exception

Answer (score 14):

According to ruby doc http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-key key(value) is the method to find the key on the base of value.

```
ROLE = {"customer" => 1, "designer" => 2, "admin" => 100}
ROLE.key(2)
```

it will return the "designer".

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

- (Object?) detect(ifnone = nil) {|obj| ... }
- (Object?) find(ifnone = nil) {|obj| ... }
- (Object) detect(ifnone = nil)
- (Object) find(ifnone = nil)

Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
(1..10).detect  {|i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> nil
(1..100).detect {|i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> 35
```

This worked for me:

```
clients.detect{|client| client.last['client_id'] == '2180' } #=> ["orange", {"client_id"=>"2180"}] 

clients.detect{|client| client.last['client_id'] == '999999' } #=> nil
```

See:
http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable#find-instance_method

Answer (score 4):

The best way to find the key for a particular value is to use key method that is available for a hash....

```
gender = {"MALE" => 1, "FEMALE" => 2}
gender.key(1) #=> MALE
```

I hope it solves your problem...

Answer (score 2):

Another approach I would try is by using `#map`

```
clients.map{ |key, _| key if clients[key] == {"client_id"=>"2180"} }.compact 
#=> ["orange"]
```

This will return all occurences of given value. The underscore means that we don't need key's value to be carried around so that way it's not being assigned to a variable. The array will contain nils if the values doesn't match - that's why I put `#compact` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an easy way to do find the keys of a given value:

```
    clients = {
      "yellow"=>{"client_id"=>"2178"}, 
      "orange"=>{"client_id"=>"2180"}, 
      "red"=>{"client_id"=>"2179"}, 
      "blue"=>{"client_id"=>"2181"}
    }

    p clients.rassoc("client_id"=>"2180")
```

...and to find the value of a given key:

```
    p clients.assoc("orange")
```

it will give you the key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

We write 2023: (so for all stumbling in here)

`find` is what you are searching for.

But `find` returns an array on match or NIL for no match. If we use the argument of `find` (a proc that is called if no match), and use `proc {[]}`, we get an empty array on a non-matching find, that fits better to a hash.

```
people = { 
    ralph: { name: "rafael", … },
    eve: { name: "eveline", … }
    …
    }
    
people[:eve] => {name: "eveline",…} 
people.find { |nick, person| person.name=="rafael" }[1] => { name: "rafael", … }
```

and

```
people[:tosca] => nil
people.find { |nick, person| person.name=="toska" }[1] => BANG ([] on nil)
```

but

```
people.find(proc {[]}) { |nick, person| person.name=="toska" }[1] => nil
```

So if you have an id-like attribute, you can do like that:

```
person=people[id]
person||=people.find({[]}) { |p| p.nick == id }[1]
person||=people.find({[]}) { |p| p.other_nick == id }[1]

raise error unless person
```