# Bidirectional Hash table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, bidirectional

I need a bidirectional Hash table in Ruby. For example:

```
h = {:abc => 123, :xyz => 789, :qaz => 789, :wsx => [888, 999]}
h.fetch(:xyz) # => 789
h.rfetch(123) # => abc
h.rfetch(789) # => [:xyz, :qaz]
h.rfetch(888) # => :wsx
```

Method `rfetch` means *reversed fetch* and is only my proposal.

Note three things:

1. If multiple keys map at the same value then `rfetch` returns all of them, packed in array.
2. If value is an array then `rfetch` looks for its param among elements of the array.
3. Bidirectional Hash means that both `fetch` and `rfetch` should execute in constant time.

Does such structure exists in Ruby (including external libraries)?

I thought about implementing it using two one-directional Hashes synchronized when one of them is modified (and packing it into class to avoid synchronization problems) but maybe I could use an already existing solution?

Comment: For a quick-and-dirty, you can use the built-in `hash.invert()` to make a separate inverse hash (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3794060/18706). As @ken-bloom points out, a more robust implementation of this is at http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/inverthash/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build something yourself pretty easily, just use a simple object that wraps two hashes (one for the forward direction, one for the reverse). For example:

```
class BiHash
    def initialize
        @forward = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
        @reverse = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
    end

    def insert(k, v)
        @forward[k].push(v)
        @reverse[v].push(k)
        v
    end

    def fetch(k)
        fetch_from(@forward, k)
    end

    def rfetch(v)
        fetch_from(@reverse, v)
    end

    protected

    def fetch_from(h, k)
        return nil if(!h.has_key?(k))
        v = h[k]
        v.length == 1 ? v.first : v.dup
    end
end
```

Look ups will behave just like normal hash lookups (because they *are* normal hash lookups). Add some operators and maybe decent `to_s` and `inspect` implementations and you're good.

Such a thing works like this:

```
b = BiHash.new
b.insert(:a, 'a')
b.insert(:a, 'b')
b.insert(:a, 'c')
b.insert(:b, 'a')
b.insert(:c, 'x')

puts b.fetch(:a).inspect            # ["a", "b", "c"]
puts b.fetch(:b).inspect            # "a"
puts b.rfetch('a').inspect          # [:a, :b]
puts b.rfetch('x').inspect          # :c
puts b.fetch(:not_there).inspect    # nil
puts b.rfetch('not there').inspect  # nil
```

There's nothing wrong with building your tools when you need them.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to return `v.dup` instead of `v` in `fetch_from`, otherwise you will could get nasty side effects, e.g. `b.rfetch(:a).pop`

Answer (score 5):

There is no such structure built-in in Ruby.

Note that `Hash#rassoc` does something similar, but it returns only the first match and is linear-time:

```
h = {:abc => 123, :xyz => 789, :qaz => 789, :wsx => [888, 999]}
h.rassoc(123) # => [:abc, 123]
```

Also, it isn't possible to fullfill your requirements in Ruby in a perfectly safe manner, as you won't be able to detect changes in values that are arrays. E.g.:

```
h = MyBidirectionalArray.new(:foo => 42, :bar => [:hello, :world])
h.rfetch(:world) # => :bar
h[:bar].shift
h[:bar] # => [:world]
h.rfetch(:world) # => should be nil, but how to detect this??
```

Computing a hash everytime to detect a change will make your lookup linear-time. You could duplicate the array-values and freeze them, though (like Ruby does for Hash keys that are strings!)

What you seem to need is a Graph class, which could have a different API than a `Hash`, no? You can check out [rgl](http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/index.html) or similar, but I don't know how they're implemented.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `Hash#invert` method (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert) to achieve this. It won't map multiple values to an array though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Hash
  def rfetch val
    select { |k,v| v.is_a?(Array) ? v.include?(val) : v == val }.map { |x| x[0] }
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest solution, however, it requires linear time so it breaks the third point mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing lots of updates to this hash, you might be able to use [inverthash](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/inverthash/).