# Find a value in a nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to do something similar to [How to find a hash key containing a matching value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794039/how-to-find-a-hash-key-containing-a-matching-value) but with a more complicated structure. Have been unsuccessful in solving this with nested map calls to hash.

```
data = {"typeA" => {
  "statX" => {
     "funcA" => {"id"=>1, "name"=>"typeA_funcA_statX"},
     "funcB" => {"id"=>7, "name"=>"typeA_funcB_statX"}
  }
}}
```

Now I want to find the id for "typeA_funcB_statX". In this instance, I was able to get the ID by using split on the name and get the id in a traditional direct hash reference:

```
type,func,stat = "typeA_funcB_statX".split("_")
id = data[type][stat][func]["id"]
```

If the name was a random string though, I was able to find the ID by writing a nested each loop (all `name` instances will be unique across the hash):

```
searchForName = "typeA_funcB_statX"
id = nil
data.each do |type,typeData|
  typeData.each do |stat,statData|
     statData.each do |func, funcData|
        id = funcData["id" if funcData["name"] == searchForName
     end
  end
end
```

I could use the `find` or `select` method when I get to the `statData` line, but would like to know how to do this more eloquently / efficiently. The complexity is making my map calls not work out. I suspect a good solution would be something with nested maps with a select / find call and maybe an invert.

*edit*

As a better example, when i am unable to use the `name` to determine any of the keys, consider this hash:

```
data = {"typeA" => {
  "statX" => {
     "funcA" => {"id"=>1, "name"=>"theFoo"},
     "funcB" => {"id"=>7, "name"=>"someBar"}
  }
} }
```

Now I want to find the ID of "theFoo" - i.e. no correlation between keys and name value.

Comment: 1. Do you mean you want to find the id for "typeA_funcB_statX" (i.e, is that a typo?)?. If "typeA_funcB_stat" is indeed what you meant, please explain the matching criterion. 2. `data` contains two errors that you should fix: a) as written, `name` must be either a local variable or method. If you mean it to be a literal, change it to `"name"` or `:name`. b) You are missing a right brace (`}`) at the very end. Be sure to check that inputs are correct. Proper formatting helps get matching pairs of `()`, `[]` and `{}` right.

Comment: Sorry, yes - a typo - `statX`

Comment: You stil need to edit to deal with my second point.

Comment: sorry, a literal. post updated. solution postd.

Comment: Your "better example" also needs another right brace at the end.

Comment: Haha, imagine syntax checking for code blocks in Stack Overflow. Or better discipline by users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116753/discussion-between-brett-and-cary-swoveland).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it with nested maps, a compact and a flatten.first:

```
fnd="theFoo"
data.map{|t,th|th.map{|s,sh|sh.map{|f,fh|fh["id"]if fh["name"]==fnd}.compact}}.flatten.first

==> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
  "typeA" => {
    "statX" => {
      "funcA" => {"id"=>1, :name=>"typeA_funcA_statX"},
      "funcB" => {"id"=>7, :name=>"typeA_funcB_statX"}
    }
  }
}
```

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
str = "typeA_funcB_statX"

data["typeA"]["statX"].values.find { |h| h[:name] == str }["id"]
  #=> 7
```

If you are not certain there will be a match on `str` (`"typeA_funcB_statX"` here), you might write

```
val = data["typeA"]["statX"].values.find { |h| h[:name] == str }
val = val["id"] unless val.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find your required 'ID',

```
data.find{ |k,v| k == "typeA"}[1].find{ |k,v| k == "statX"}[1]
.find{ |k,v| k == "funcB"}[1]["id"]

==> 7
```

Comment: Hi Sravan, I was not clear in how I asked my question - I want to find a way to get the ID without specifying any of the keys of the hash, i.e. using map / find. I have added a new example of a hash to use. Looking for a single line way to find it, instead of nested `.each` loops.