# How can i search a value in Ruby Hash Table?

Tags: ruby

```
area_dictionary = {
  "Alabama" => "205",
  "Alaska" => "907",
  "American Samoa" =>"684",
  "Arizona" => "480",
  "Arkansas" => "479",
  "California" => "209",
  "Colorado" => "303",
  "Connecticut" => "203",
  "Delaware" => "302",
  "Florida" => "239",
  "Georgia" => "229",
  "Guam" => "671",
  "Hawaii" => "808"
}

def get_city_name(hash,key)
    hash.each{|k,v|puts k if v==key}
end
    puts"Please enter the code for which you want to find the city?"
    code = gets.chomp
    if area_dictionary.include?(code)#getting trouble from here
      puts "The city for #{code}is#{get_city_name(area_dictionary,code)}"
    end
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched for this? I imagine information on this should be everywhere.

Comment: I recommend reading [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html).

Comment: def get_city_name(hash,key)
    hash.each{|k,v|puts k if v==key}
end
puts "Please enter the code for which you want to find the city?"
            code = gets.chomp
            if area_dictionary.include?(code)
                puts "The city for #{code} is #{get_city_name(area_dictionary,code)}"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: Sorry, getting trouble in posting the question. New to this website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a hash key containing a matching value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794039/how-to-find-a-hash-key-containing-a-matching-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find the key for a value, you can use the following:

```
area_dictionary.invert['239']
=> "Florida"
```

If you are simply trying to get the value for a given key, you can use the following:

```
area_dictionary['Florida']
=> "239"
```

Comment: I need to search whether '239' is present in the hash or not
like 
code = gets.chomp
if area_dictionary.include?(code)

Comment: You can also use method area_dictionary.has_value?('239')

Answer (score 0):

Some self-explanatory examples

```
area_dictionary["Alaska"]
 => "907"
area_dictionary["Alaskaaaa"]
 => nil
area_dictionary.fetch("Alaska")
 => "907"
area_dictionary.fetch("Alaskaaaa")
 KeyError: key not found: "Alaskaaaa"
    from (irb):5:in `fetch'
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
area_dictionary.fetch("Alaskaaaa", 10)
 => 10
area_dictionary.values_at("Alabama", "Alaska")
 => ["205", "907"]
```