# Extracting specific keys from a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this code wherein it's retrieving data from table_reward that suppose to retrieve rewards that is equal or below 50 points. This is the code:

```
def index
    @user = User.find_by_id(1)
    user_point = @user.point

    @rewards = Reward.all
    @final = @rewards.each_with_object({}) do |reward, points|
        points[reward[:id]] = reward[:point] < user_point
    end

    @http_status = 200
    @http_response[:status] = true
    @http_response[:results] = @final 

    render :json => @http_response.to_json, :status => @http_status
end
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The problem is, it should only display the data of each reward that has below or equal to 50 points not all the rewards.

Comment: You can answer your own question and earn some points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided the link below that answers my question, for future help.

[Extracting specific keys from a hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794053/8596800)